# Rotate & Scale a gif animation using 2 finger gesture in Android using Fresco Library

Tags: android, scale, animated-gif, image-rotation, fresco

How to Rotate & Scale a gif animation using 2 finger gesture in Andriod using Fresco Library.

Hi I'm trying to perform Translate, Scale and Rotate on View (FrameLayout) in android.

In brief, I've a Fresco's SimpleDraweeView inside FrameLayout, as Fresco is not supporting Matrix transformations, so as an alternative I put that in FrameLayout and doing Translation, Rotation and Scaling.

The transformation is going out of screen...

Any reference or code samples will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample library Fresco has released covering this case:
 https://github.com/facebook/fresco/tree/master/samples/zoomable/src/main/java/com/facebook/samples/zoomable

which uses

https://github.com/facebook/fresco/tree/master/samples/gestures/src/main/java/com/facebook/samples/gestures